# Facebook Video Upload Issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, upload

I use facebook blog' [code](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/493/) for video uploading. It seems work correctly but there is a problem of the video ID.

here's my sample page http://2arti1.com/fb

im firstly upload the video, and graphAPI.facebook.com gives me an video id but when i get the Facebook video page which is facebook.com/photo.php?v=myVideoID  it says:

> This content is currently unavailable

what sholud i do about this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have been testing some video upload logic right now as well and I have learned 2 things that may be causing your issue.

First, it will depend on if you are posting this video for public or private viewing (Friends, or anyone).  If you try to use a path similar to what you have in your post and you **ARE NOT** logged in - you won't see the video.  If you ARE logged in, it may just take a few minutes.

Second, it may just need time to propagate in the FB system.  I have used debugging tool with the open graph to post a video, then run a routine to check the graph feed until it return the video metadata I want (IE. thumbnail, source, etc).

TRY a path like so every 15 second until you see the graph data: **"https://graph.facebook.com/" + video_id**;

My tests show it takes about 2-3 minutes before open graph calls return object data around your video.

Hope this helps!